# S3 bucket policy to set a folder readable by a referring URL, and another folder only available to AWS user

Tags: amazon-s3, bucket, policies

We have a structure with a Laravel app running in URL www.example.com and connected to a bucket with 3 folders inside.

```
folder_a
folder_b
folder_c
```

Ideally, we would like the app to be able to:

- Upload objects to the three folders
- Get objects from folder_a (but only on requests that come from www.example.com/example.com and not everywhere on internet (avoiding hotlinking and direct URL access)

Also, `folder_b` and `folder_c` should be absolutely forbidden from internet (not listing folder, nor getting an object even knowing the URL)
At the same time, the IAM user should be able to access everything, upload/download/edit/delete everything.

We have tried lots of bucket policies without success. We have successfully created the IAM user, and our Laravel app is already sending objects to the S3.

> NOTE: This is not about Laravel configuration, it's about S3 bucket policies. The app is already sending objects to S3 correctly, and all objects are public now

Comment: Does any part of your Laravel App requires any part of the S3 bucket to be public accessible?

Comment: Sorry I didn't see this comment before. The Laravel app retrieve images from folder_a that has to be shown on a timeline. Assets for the app are outside of S3. Think of the app as a feed page: people upload their pictures, the app store the pictures on the S3, and then the app retrieves that pictures from the S3 to show them to other users

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Assuming eventually, you would like to get rid of the public accessibility of your S3 bucket, because it is generally a bad idea, unless you are only allowing some static, harmless files.

Here is the bucket policy:

```
{
    "Version": "2012-10-17",
    "Statement": [
        // this one make sure only ListBucket api calls from laravel user are allowed
        {
            "Effect": "Allow",
            "Principal": {
                "AWS": "arn:aws:iam::1234567890:user/<laravel_iam_user>"
            },
            "Action": [
                "s3:ListBucket"
            ],
            "Resource": [
                "arn:aws:s3:::<yourbucket>"
            ]
        },
        // this one make sure only upload api calls from laravel user are allowed
        {
            "Effect": "Allow",
            "Principal": {
                "AWS": "arn:aws:iam::1234567890:user/<laravel_iam_user>"
            },
            "Action": [
                "s3:PutObject"
            ],
            "Resource": [
                "arn:aws:s3:::<yourbucket>/folder_a/*",
                "arn:aws:s3:::<yourbucket>/folder_b/*",
                "arn:aws:s3:::<yourbucket>/folder_c/*"
            ]
        },
        // this one make sure only download api calls from www.example.com/example.com are allowed
        {
            "Effect": "Allow",
            "Principal": "*",
            "Action": [
                "s3:GetObject"
            ],
            "Resource": [
                "arn:aws:s3:::<yourbucket>/folder_a/*"
            ],
            "Condition": {
               "StringLike": {"aws:Referer":["http://www.example.com/*","http://example.com/*"]}
            }
        }
    ]
}
```

Edit: since the OP actually want public access on part of the bucket, should not check all 4 public access block settings.

Comment: I'm afraid that's not a valid solution. With that policy in place, and even selecting the last option on the "Block Public Access" (Block public and cross-account access to buckets and objects through any public bucket policies) objects at `folder_b` and `folder_c` are still downloadable from internet. 
If I apply the 4 checks on the "Block Public Access" nothing is public, not even the objects on `folder_a`

Also, there's a mistake on the policy: the resource for the first block (s3:ListBucket) needs to be the bucket alone. If I add the slash and the asterisk, AWS doesn't allow me to save.

Comment: I edited the answer. So I meant to apply all 4 checks. Why do you need public access for objects under folder_a? You mentioned "app retrieves that pictures from the S3 to show them to other users". In that case, it is only your app that actually download the object. So, the Condition can actually be removed, since only <laravel_iam_user>, aka your app, are allowed to download the object under folder_a.

Comment: But the app uses those pictures to show them to the user, so they have to be available to be shown on the browser. 
I don't know if I'm making it clear enough, but objects in `folder_a` has to be publicity visible, but only for requests from www.example.com (however they need to be shown on the browser by a simple `<img src="...">` tag (We're not reading the object in the app and showing ourselves anyhow)

Comment: Finally you made it clear. Edited the answer again, basically just changed the principal to everybody ("*") and add back the condition of the hostname. For public access block, you can at most check the first two regarding ACLs. But if your code put object with public ACL, you cannot check them either.

Comment: Worked like a charm! Thanks a lot! :)

Answer (score 0):

Give bucket public access by removing check from block public

then this bucket policy works:

```
// this one make sure only download api calls from www.example.com/example.com are allowed
    {
        "Effect": "Allow",
        "Principal": "*",
        "Action": [
            "s3:GetObject"
        ],
        "Resource": [
            "arn:aws:s3:::<yourbucket>/folder_a/*"
        ],
        "Condition": {
           "StringLike": {"aws:Referer":["http://www.example.com/*","http://example.com/*"]}
        }
    }
```

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).